# General purpose Android phone music controls from Android Wear watch

Tags: android, wear-os, android-music-player

On my Android Wear 2.0 watch, if it's connected to my phone via Bluetooth, when I play music on my phone from any source, the watch automatically switches to some generic audio control app from which I can play/pause/skip/etc on my phone.

This makes me think there must be some interface that would allow me to implement those basic media controls from an app that I'm developing. I haven't been able to find any info, though.

Does anybody have any info about doing that on Android Wear?

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [sample codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-music-player/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Fio2017#0) on how to adapt a music player app to work seamlessly on Android Wear using the latest Android media APIs.

If you use the media APIs, your users can control playback and browse songs on their Android Wear devices without any additional code. With this tutorial, Android Wear automatically connects to the `MediaSessionCompat` linked by a `MediaStyle` notification. The latest version of Android Wear also connects to the `MediaBrowserServiceCompat` for browsing content.

You may also check this [tutorial](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer) on how to  implement an audio media app that works across multiple form factors and provide a consistent user experience on Android phones, tablets, Android Auto, **Android Wear**, Android TV and Google Cast devices.

Comment: Thank you, but I think this tutorial shows how to accomplish what I already mention working in my question - implement my own media player for mobile so that a Wear device will automatically get control over it. I want to implement functionality in my Wear app to control OTHER media players on the Mobile device. In this past, this would have been possible using RemoteController.OnClientUpdateListener - but that has been deprecated, and requires MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL permission, which is not available to 3rd party apps anymore.

Answer (score 0):

See AudioManager.dispatchMediaKeyEvent(KeyEvent keyEvent)

Obviously this code needs to run on what device you want to control. So you could have in run from a WearableListenerService on the phone responding to messages from wear.

The dispatchMediaKeyEvent is Kitkat and above. To support earlier versions you broadcast intents. Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.

Both of these need key down and up events to work, or at least on some devices.

```
long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - 1;
KeyEvent downEvent = new KeyEvent(eventTime,eventTime,KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PAUSE, 0);
audioManager.dispatchMediaKeyEvent(downEvent);

eventTime++;
KeyEvent upEvent = new KeyEvent(eventTime, eventTime, KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PAUSE, 0);
audioManager.dispatchMediaKeyEvent(upEvent);
```